# C Pointers - Invalid Conversion from Char to Char*

Tags: java, c, pointers, char, java-native-interface

I'm currently coding a Java application which loads a native library coded in C.
A C function which gets called from Java is passed a jchar.
In that C function, another library gets loaded with a new function which needs the jchar converted to a char* pointer.
All I know about that new function is that it takes a pointer to a char value as parameter (char* parity).

This is my current code:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_analyzer_DeclareNative_init (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, ... , jchar parity, ...) {

    typedef int (__stdcall *Init) (..., char* parity, ...);
    HINSTANCE hinstLib = LoadLibrary("rs232");

    Init initcon = (Init) GetProcAdress(hinstLib, "functionname");

    char p = (char) parity;  //(Typecasting jchar to char)
    char *pchar = &p;  //(Creating a pointer to p)

    initcon(..., *pchar, ...);
}
```

When I try to compile this code, it throws following error:
"Invalid conversion from char to char*"

Comment: why are you passing '*pchar' and not 'pchar'?

Comment: Post self-contained code and especially java declaration of native method and its JNI implementation.

Comment: Bytheway - I see no `jchar` in code. Where it comes from?

Comment: @bmargulies I printed for testing purposes *pchar and pchar to the console, but pchar lead to NNN�<��<� and *pchar to N

Comment: Are you sure that `initcon()`'s `parity` is a pointer to single char, not to string?

Comment: @Serhio Yes, I got a documentation about the functions from the rs232 library where it is clearly stated that a pointer to a char value is required

Comment: What's the meaning of the `...` ellipsis?  In ansi-c it is a specific token with an also specific meaning.  Why don't you post exact, compilable and testable examples with clear as stated error messages?  Do you think we are all in your head and see things like you?  Think that is such that thing where the fact, all of us should be committing the same mistake as you and will need SO recursively to ask the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @bmargulies already pointed out, the problem here is that you are not passing `pchar` (which is of type `(char *)`, but `*pchar`. `*` is a dereferencing operator and it means "give me whatever is at the address pointed to by `pchar`. In other words - a single `char`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your function parameters you'll see that `parity`is coming in as a `char *`, yet further down you have this line:

```
char p = (char) parity;
```

You're casting a char pointer to a char. You don't need to do this based upon what you appear to need on the next line:

```
char *pchar = &p;
```

You already have parity as a `char *` as a result of the parameter being passed in.

Answer (score 0):

`jchar` is a single 16-bit, UTF-16, Unicode character. '&' of it is *not* `char *`, and will not work passed to a `char *`. You need to convert it to the ACP and null-terminate it. `WideCharToMultiByte` might prove helpful.